# Downloading speed in google chrome is very slow

Tags: networking, google-chrome, windows-8.1

I just installed a new windows 8.1 pro 64bit system on my new SSD.

After installing chrome (Version 39.0.2171.95 m) I noticed download speed is terrible, `7 kb/s` on average.

On [speedtest.net](http://www.speedtest.net/) it is `4mb/s` on steam it is also `4mb/s`, then why is it so slow on chrome?

I checked my connection, restarted the modem also checked for updates for my network card. Still speed is very slow. I am not using wifi.

What might be the issue here?

Comment: Have you tried download different files from other websites?

Comment: I have. Issue came up for all those files

Comment: Can you give some examples of what and from where you are trying to download?

Comment: Nvidia drivers, vlc player, ccleaner. Etc.

Comment: Try download these files in IE. If still throttle, it may not a Chrome specific issue.

Comment: This might be a silly question, but have you tried updating CHrome? Version 39 seems quite old to the latest version 115.0.5790.7

Answer (score 0):

Try this, you need to switch on this feature called parallel download in chrome://flags, this will increase the speed of chrome downloading things. Parallel downloads are simply multiple downloads that take place concurrently across multiple domains hosted by one host. It reduces the time it takes for a connection to be complete which results in faster page loading and download speeds